# Can a Dashboard widget use SQLite data?

Tags: macos, dashboard

I made an iOS app that has my favorite quotes in it by category. I wanted to turn this into a dashboard widget that notifies me of a quote of the day. I've never made a dashboard widget and only read the hello world example on apple site.

Can anyone suggest a good tutorial or help me understand the following:

What is the best way to take my SQLite database of quotes and make it available through a dashboard widget?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dashboard is, like, really old... it has the look of a technology that's barely clinging to life support.

But if you want to fool around with it anyway, the way to access SQLite from a widget would be to implement a [native widget plug-in](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashboard_ProgTopics/Articles/WidgetPlugin.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003051-SW1) that uses the SQLite library, exposing methods that your widget JavaScript code can call to fetch the info you need.

Or, as you seem to have done, repackage the data in a different form that you can access more conveniently from widget JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for your response and that is what I figured. :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using NerdTools and implemented an awk script to pull a random quote from a text file on my computer. So this was solved a different way.